# What are medals for? Or how to show them?

Tags: battlefield-1

So I completed all the missions from a specific active medal. When I go to **Select Medal** I can see everything with a *tick*, what now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what it looks like, the medal system is nothing more than a way of keeping players active and a way of awarding active players XP.

I have seen nothing about actually displaying these medals or anything about the purpose of the medals beyond an xp reward system.

The ticks displayed are most likely a way of notifying the player that they have indeed completed the requirements for the medal in question.

If I see anything I'll update my answer and keep you posted.

I hope this answers your question

Comment: Really? I had the hope I was missing something.The XP thing is *OK* but showing them would be nice. Thanks for the info

Comment: yeah it seems like a bit of a waste having a whole system made and not allowing players to display what they have worked for

Comment: At least we take the XP, *it's something* :D

Comment: Some also give dog tags (maybe even all of them)